# iText7: Parsing html with ul in td does not show list-style element

Tags: java, itext7, html2pdf

We are about to find out if iText7 fits our needs.

Our workflow is as follow: we send an html body (almost tables; build by php) and some css with REST to a Java prototype app. There the html is put through the HtmlConverter and onto the PdfDocument.

Most of the output of the resulting pdf looks fine, but we do not see any glyph in front of the li elements of ul's and ol's. We already tried to force it with css:

```
ol li { list-style-type: disc; }
```

But with no success. Also we tried other definitions (list-style: disc inside; list-style: disc outside; list-style: disc; or list-style-type: disc;) in ul, ol and/or li.

The css is parsed fine btw. we've changed the background-color of ul/ol which works.

We also tested several font files, but can not get the glyphs displayed.

Any suggenstions?

Comment: What if you don't define a list-style? Do you get a hyphen or a bullet? If so, it could be a font-related problem. The disc symbol isn't a common glyph that is present in a standard font. Maybe iText 7 and pdfHTML aren't finding any disc symbol in the fonts at hand. If so, maybe adding an extra font to the `FontProvider` could solve the problem. If you don't see any list symbol (not even a hyphen) if you omit the list style, then something else is at play. Or if you can make a disc show up in a list outside a `<td>`, then my comment doesn't make much sense.

Comment: At first we didn't put any css on the ul's/ol's with the same results. We've also tried list-style-type: square/circle/etc. I just tried to just put a plain list without table around to the pdf - it renders also without glyph.

Comment: Also without css: no glyphs. We're using arialuni.ttf as font.

Comment: OK, then the problem isn't related to glyphs. Something else must be at play. I'm in the middle of doing something else, but if this doesn't get picked up by tomorrow. I'll make an example to reproduce the problem and I'll create an internal ticket at iText Software.

Comment: Ok, I found out something: To get the glyphs, I had to do three things: 1) remove the font arialuni, 2) Change `"<style>" + css + "</style>" + body` to `"<html><head>" + css + "</head><body>" + body + "</body></html>"` and 3) remove padding: 0; in css. Now I have two glyphs in a nested list, but this is a css thing I guess.

Comment: Seems that it won't work even with other fonts. I tested it with several fonts which I downloaded or took from Windows font folder. The glyphs are only showing up if I do not declare a font - than the default font is used.

Comment: The mistake was on our side: we created the font with PdfFontFactory.createFont(this.FONT, PdfEncodings.UTF8); and added it to the font provider with PdfEncodings.UTF8 again. After removing, it works fine.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could share the self-reproducible piece of code demonstrating the problem. `list-style-type: disc;` snippet is not enough because `pdfHTML` supports it and there are a lot of tests for that. The devil is in the details so please share as many of them as you can.

Comment: @manuxi Please either make a description of the error with the font an answer which you (after some hours) can mark as accepted or remove the question altogether. Questions without answers on stack overflow are treated differently from questions with accepted answers, so your question would be treated inadequately.

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We created the font in the wrong way:

```
this.font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(this.FONT, PdfEncodings.UTF8);
this.fontProvider = new FontProvider();
this.fontProvider.addFont(font.getFontProgram(), PdfEncodings.UTF8);
```

This works correct:

```
this.font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(this.FONT, PdfEncodings.UTF8);
this.fontProvider = new FontProvider();
this.fontProvider.addFont(font.getFontProgram());
```